# Unable to play a .mp3 file directly using QTMovie

Tags: cocoa, audio

I am trying to play a .mp3 file on click of a button using this code:

```
NSString *audioFilePath=[[audioInputTextField stringValue] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *audioUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:audioFilePath];
QTMovie* soundToPlay = [[QTMovie alloc] initWithURL:audioUrl error:nil];
[soundToPlay play];
```

Here user is expected to enter a valid url for an audio file in text field and then click button next to it to play, but it is not working for me ie. no audio gets played :(

Can anyone suggest me, if I am doing anything wrong?

Thanks,

Miraaj

---

The sample code can be downloaded from here- [Sample Code download link](http://db.tt/cDjFCZO)

One of the example links which I tried was - [In the end song](http://javamax.free.fr/sonorisation%20et%20radio/Linken%20Park%20-%20In%20The%20End.mp3)

Comment: Don't suppress the error return. There's a good chance that QTMovie can tell you what's wrong, but you're not letting it. Pass a pointer to an `NSError *` variable, then when `soundToPlay` is `nil`, log the error object that `initWithURL:error:` gave you in the variable.

Comment: @Miraaj do you have complete that task? please have a look on my similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293840/play-audio-from-url-in-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

Is audioFilePath a valid file system path? Is audioUrl a valid file URL or is it nil? To me it looks unlikely since you're giving a url-encoded path and trying to initialize a new URL with that string.

Your audioFilePath should be a valid /Path/To/Folder/File.mp3 and if you have a basic file path, you should create your URL with NSURL's +fileURLWithPath: convenience method.

Comment: thanx for your reply and suggestion... it is a valid path which I gave, eg-http://javamax.free.fr/sonorisation%20et%20radio/Linken%20Park%20-%20In%20The%20End.mp3, but it did not work. You can download the sample application and check it.

Comment: I think there can be some problem with the way audio file is buffered and played... but it is a guess I am still searching for its solution!

Comment: Ah so it's not a file path as the variable name suggests. :-) This should work. What happens when you set a breakpoint just after the NSURL creation line and inspect audioUrl? Is it valid or nil?

Answer (score 0):

You entered a URL with characters already percent-escaped, and then your program added percent escapes. This means that you double-escaped the characters, turning the correct “%20”s into incorrect “%2520”s.

Try it both ways: Try the URL without escaping first, then if it fails, add percent escapes and try again. If *that* fails, present the error that `initWithURL:error:` gave you.

Comment: thanx...for your reply :) I will check it and let you know about it!

Comment: @Peter Hosey  please have a look on my similar question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293840/play-audio-from-url-in-mac-os-x